# Find specific string from a XML clob column in oracle

Tags: oracle, xpath, oracle11g, xml-namespaces

Can someone let me know how I can extract only the URL that ends with .xsd from the 2nd line of the below 2 sample xml's by using regx/any other command in oracle.

Please note-This entire xml is stored in a CLOB column of a table in oracle.

below are some sample xml's-

**Sample 1**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <TestReport xmlns="https://www.fake.org/sites/defaults/files/2022-12/TestReport.xsd">
    <indl xmlns="">
    ----
    ---
    --
    </indl>
</TestReport>
```

**Sample 2**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <TestReport xmlns="https://www.fake.org/xsd/TestReport" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w2.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.fake.org/xsd/TestReport https://www.fake.org/sites/default/files/2023-01/TestReport.xsd">
    <indl xmlns="">
    ----
    ---
    --
    </indl>
</TestReport>
```

Comment: It is invalid XML because `TestReport` doesn't have closing tag

Comment: I added the closing tag.

Comment: @MT0 the second XML sample is not about XML namespace, but another attribute (seems to be some part of XMLSchema which *may* require additional parsing according to schema rules). It is not exact duplicate